# Bash script to list specific file types and write to file?

Tags: regex, bash, grep, ls

Just starting out with bash and I'm having a little trouble getting this script to work. I'm wanting it to list the contents of a directory and output only certain file types to a `.txt`.

An example of what I've got so far when trying to list only `.pdf`, `.txt` and `.doc` files is below, just wondering where about I've gone wrong?

```
#!/bin/bash
ls -a | grep -vi '*.(pdf|txt|doc)$' $1 > contents.txt
```

Comment: Read up on find. As to your solution, you want to grep the input from the pipe, not a file specified on the command line (`$1`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By the way, you can do this without `grep` and regex, i.e.

```
ls -a *.{pdf,txt,doc} > contents.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

You missed to escape some characters within your regular expression, take a look at this:

```
#!/bin/bash
ls -a | grep -i '.*\.\(pdf\|txt\|doc\)$' $1 > contents.txt
```

Also, delete the `-v` option from the command, because it instructs `grep` to pass those 
entries that **don't** match the regexp

If you don't want to escape regexp chars, consider using `egrep` instead